# could not read pdf file

Tags: php

adobe reader could not open a.pdf because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged(for example , it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded)  show this error when open downloaded pdf file in php . i used the following code:

```
header('Content-disposition:attachment;filename=customer_acc_info_form.pdf');
header('Content-type:application/pdf');
readfile('bo_account/customer_acc_info_form.pdf');

<li><a href="customer_acc_info_form.php">Customer Account Information Form</a></li>
```

Comment: Is the `<li>` tag part of the same script that generates PDF?

Answer (score 3):

You should remove the `<li>...</li>` from the PHP file. It's going to be appended at the end of the PDF file (after the readfile call) and cause it to be invalid. Make sure that there is nothing else sent after the file.

Comment: no ,its not correct. here <li></li> used for link created

Comment: I understand that you use it to create the PDF file but if it's in the same file as the the one that's sending the file, it's probably including that `<li>...</li>` bit after reading the file. You should put an `exit;` right after readfile and move the `<li>...</li>` to another file.